# How to fix an element position with the specific of father element When matching browsers of different sizes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I don't know how to search the same question in `Stack Overflow`. So, I ask this question.

I set two buttons `position: absolute;` and their father element `position: relative;`. 
If the big **Chrome Window**, they are beautiful. When use mouse the change the window size to a smaller size. The buttons locate a wrong position.They are ugly.
As Image below:

The big window: 
The red button and green button at the position I need.
[image]

The small window: 
The red button and green button at the wrong position.

[image]

In the small window, two buttons located at the center position.(I looked like they at the center position.)

**What I want to need them at the same right nor top percenter position in the blue element.**

My code is below:

```
<style>
        .content {
            width: 100vw;
        }
        #fullpage .section img {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 1200px;
            display: block;
        }
        .apple {
            position: absolute;
            right: 300px;
            top: -560px;
            width: 350px;
            height: 90px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        .apple:hover {
            background: url("./img/Andriod-hover.png");
        }
        .android {
            position:relative;
            right: 300px;
            top: -660px;
            width: 350px;
            height: 90px;
            background-color: green;
        }
        .android:hover {
            background: url("./img/iphone-hover.png");
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullpage.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullpage.css" />
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
      sectionsColor : ['#58C0F2','#FBFFF1', '#FBFFF1'],
    });
  });
</script>
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section section1">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="" alt="">
                <div class="apple"></div>
                <div class="android"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

To tell you the truth, the two buttons in the blue father element is the `iOS` and `Android` download button. I need to match browsers of different sizes.

=============

I'm sorry, my description not enough. I add to real Image below.

The right position:

[image]

The small size and the wrong position: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you don't want the buttons to be moved when the browser resizes, try this

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
}

.btnHolder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 80%;
  transform: translate(-80%, -50%);
}

.btnHolder button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="btnHolder">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
</div>
```

This will position the buttons always on the right side, even with resizing.

I didn't use your codes so that I can provide the minimal way to position without being moved when resizing, just use the css that I used, adjust the values accordingly, and don't use pixels, always percent so that it will not move

Comment: I add to images in my descript will.  I am sorry. I lost your time. If I need use the pixels unit. Are you have any idea?

Comment: Should it really be positioned absolutely? From what I can see in the image, three inline div should do it, so that the buttons will not overlap the other elements

Comment: I set `.btnHolder ` position at the center bottom point in the body element, and set the button's position as `position:absolute,  top: -200px`.

Answer (score -1):

Admittedly,  I'm still relatively new to programming so this answer may not be correct,  but do you have bootstrap?  If so you could apply the "container-fluid" class to the parent  elements and that should allow them to adjust their size according to the size of the screen viewing them.

If I am wrong or if there is a better solution please correct me.